# How replace bootstrap-vue dropdown caret icon with another icon?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

This is a bootstrap-vue dropdown  which its icon is a caret.

```
<div>
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

How change it to a calendar icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Vue.component('customIcon', {
  template: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15.352" height="15.355" viewBox="0 0 15.352 15.355">
        <path id="Union_19" data-name="Union 19" d="M-19.5-15958.5l-7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5Z" transform="translate(27.176 15966.178)" fill="none" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    </svg>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown no-caret>
    <template #button-content>
        Custom Dropdown
        <custom-icon /> // or any other icons 
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

Can add a template for it.